# WSL. Empty output file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2015, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working with WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) in Visual Studio 2015.
And I want to avoid copy sources to linux machine.
I changed "Copy Sources" field to "No".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUnk9.png)

And set "Remote Build Project Directory" field to linux path to my project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Duo.png)

Project builds successfully but output file is empty(size is zero bytes).

Also intermediate files looks normal, so it shouldn't be access rights issue.

So, why output file is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

After setting option "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Projects and Solutions" -> "Build and Run" -> "MSBuild project output verbosity" from "Minimal" to "Diagnostic" in log I saw this line: "Copying file '/mnt/c/ivovchenko/Documents/linux_build/TestProject/TestProject/bin/x64/Debug/TestProject.out' to 'C:\ivovchenko\Documents\linux_build\TestProject\TestProject\bin\x64\Debug\TestProject.out' (TaskId:44)"

MSBuild copies file in its own location and in some reason it becomes empty.

So I set option "Copy Output" to "No". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gC4V.png)

And it solved problem.